# Access denied Error in MySQL and Drupal

Tags: mysql, backup, mysqldump

We are trying to deploy a Drupal application on our production server.

We see this strange error `Lost connection to MySQL server at ''Access denied root@ipaddres password(yes)` after deploying.

We made all necessary corrections in `settings.php` and also give `GRANTs` to the webserver to access the database.  The webserver and the database server are physically two different machines.

We are able to connect to the database server from our web server through the command line.

There is no firewall enabled on either server.

Any update we make to the database means the site goes down and displays an `ACCESS DENIED` error.

Can any one guide me to resolve this issue?

Thanks

Comment: It a bit hard to tell. Could you supply a bit more info about your setup, ie OS, MySQL version, settings.php line etc?

Answer (score 1):

1. May be lame to do this but worthy to double check the username and password and ip. "Copy paste the exact connect string in commandline"
2. Triage more by only keeping DB connection from app/web server and check the DB connectivity  functionality and see if the issue repeats. If yes, do the same from someother host with same app/web interface server version. [with this we can be sure that the host is no problem] .